# CORS Preflight request denied

Tags: php, laravel, ionic-framework, cors, middleware

There is a **login API** and put it in **CORS** middleware to run it from elsewhere like -

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors']], function () { 
     Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
});
```

The middleware **'cors'** is written in $routeMiddleware in **'kernel.php'** file like

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //some other middlewares 
    'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class, 
];
```

And **in the same file**, a **variable** named **$middleware** is defined as

```
protected $middleware = [
    // Some similar classes 
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];
```

And **Cors.php** contains the following code

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Accept, Authorization'
    ];
    if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
        return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
    }

    $response = $next($request);
    foreach($headers as $key => $value)
        $response->header($key, $value);
    return $response;
}
```

Now, when I use this Login API from a **mobile App** then it gives the following error on the system

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '.../laravel/public/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

And/Or, in another word, I am not able to log in.

Please help me in solving this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: The preflight request is an OPTIONS request, make sure your system handles that one correctly. (Right now, I only see `Route::post` there in your CORS setup, so I am assuming that OPTIONS likely does not get handled correctly yet. Don’t know the specifics of settings this up in Laravel though.)

Comment: use your system ip if you are trying to hit on local like  http:// yourip/api dont use localhost

Comment: I have handled  OPTIONS request in Cors.php

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have mixed up two different CORS implementations.

As of Laravel 7x, CORS handling is built into Laravel using the `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors` middleware. Your CORS configuration is handled in the `config/cors.php` file.

You can remove your custom `\App\Http\Middleware\Cors` class, and just update your `config/cors.php` file to include the CORS available paths. By default, all of your `api` routes are already included.

Comment: Okay, I have removed the custom 
`'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class`    from kernel.php file  
then How do I have to use     `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class` middleware in api.php file Or How can I write login api  `Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);` in api.php file.

Comment: @dedrajsharma The `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors` middleware is already a global middleware defined in your kernel. You don't need to attempt to assign it to any routes. You do, however, need to update your `config/cors.php` file to include any routes you want to be CORS enabled. Unless you've changed it, the default install already includes `'api/*'`, so any routes defined in your `api.php` route file will already work.

Comment: @dedrajsharma No problem. I'd suggest marking this as the accepted answer to let others know it solved this problem, in case they come across the same issue.

Comment: Yup thanks, this is what I have done, but in my case all the routes in api are working fine except the one which also is inside api,php. Can you shed some light to this?